# Ubuntu freezes on suspend on Lenovo E490, L380 and L390

Tags: suspend, laptop, lenovo, intel, thinkpad

After a recent Ubuntu kernel update different Thinkpad devices have trouble going to suspend.
Almost every time they go to suspend on lid-close, they lock up hard and is only recoverable by long-pressing the power button (hard shutoff).

One case with an E490 running `5.0.0-25-generic`: I believe the lid-close was at the start of this `/var/log/kern.log` 12:47, and it looks like multiple suspend attempts happened. 13:39 is the boot after hard shutoff.:

```
Aug 25 12:47:52 otter kernel: [ 6136.106453] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.106455] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.111011] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.113424] OOM killer disabled.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.113425] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.114802] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.251442] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.546434] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.593244] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.604828] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.604829] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.604830] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.604846] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.606870] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.613456] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.619164] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.623756] IRQ 149: no longer affine to CPU4
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.624811] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.629405] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.629414] IRQ 139: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.630465] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.635297] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU6
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.635310] IRQ 148: no longer affine to CPU6
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.636359] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.641122] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU7
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.641129] IRQ 126: no longer affine to CPU7
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.641136] IRQ 129: no longer affine to CPU7
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.641143] IRQ 140: no longer affine to CPU7
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.641150] IRQ 141: no longer affine to CPU7
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.642214] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.651258] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.651374] ACPI: EC: EC started
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.651375] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.657806] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.657930] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.657931] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.667378]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.667608] CPU1 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.667633] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.668092]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.668250] CPU2 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.668283] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.668742]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.668910] CPU3 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.668930] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.669491]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.669808] CPU4 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.669833] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.670287]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.670474] CPU5 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.670496] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.670948]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.671148] CPU6 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.671168] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.671621]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.671829] CPU7 is up
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.679029] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.717157] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.766127] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.774036] ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.871846] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6136.991756] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.013757] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.289685] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.520821] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4694]
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.553042] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1162..]
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.565726] usb 1-5: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.798788] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.798850] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.798909] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.800931] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801974] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801975] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801976] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801977] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801977] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801979] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.801982] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-18-16-1.sfi
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.805776] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.837393] OOM killer enabled.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6137.837393] Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6138.094053] PM: suspend exit
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6138.199305] Generic PHY r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
Aug 25 12:47:54 otter kernel: [ 6138.327732] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Aug 25 12:47:55 otter kernel: [ 6139.403514] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Aug 25 12:47:55 otter kernel: [ 6139.403811] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1566813 usecs
Aug 25 12:47:55 otter kernel: [ 6139.403825] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Aug 25 12:47:55 otter kernel: [ 6139.416945] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12824 usecs
Aug 25 12:47:55 otter kernel: [ 6139.416947] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-18-16-1.ddc
Aug 25 12:47:55 otter kernel: [ 6139.419970] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.903302] wlp5s0: authenticate with d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.912998] wlp5s0: send auth to d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a (try 1/3)
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.952485] wlp5s0: authenticated
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.953501] wlp5s0: associate with d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a (try 1/3)
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.955384] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=7)
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.959582] wlp5s0: associated
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6141.980381] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
Aug 25 12:47:58 otter kernel: [ 6142.099071] wlp5s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a
Aug 25 12:48:22 otter kernel: [ 6166.146515] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 25 12:48:22 otter kernel: [ 6166.146518] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.158103] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.160547] OOM killer disabled.
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.160547] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.161985] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.303257] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from d8:0d:17:ad:19:0a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.599513] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.642537] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.653850] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.653851] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.653852] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.653866] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.655836] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.658706] irq_migrate_all_off_this_cpu: 6 callbacks suppressed
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.658709] IRQ 147: no longer affine to CPU2
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.659761] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.662593] IRQ 143: no longer affine to CPU3
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.663653] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.666564] IRQ 141: no longer affine to CPU4
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.666583] IRQ 149: no longer affine to CPU4
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.668360] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.671068] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.671076] IRQ 126: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.671084] IRQ 142: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.671093] IRQ 146: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.672115] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.674613] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU6
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.674630] IRQ 144: no longer affine to CPU6
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.675659] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.679224] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.684582] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.684696] ACPI: EC: EC started
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.684697] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.691199] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.691291] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.691293] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.694806]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.697184] CPU1 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.697216] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.699435]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.699596] CPU2 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.699619] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.700090]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.700259] CPU3 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.700288] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.700832]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.701156] CPU4 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.701179] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.701636]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.701828] CPU5 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.701859] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.702341]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.702535] CPU6 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.702556] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.703026]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.703236] CPU7 is up
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.710404] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.750905] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning ON
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.751874] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.804415] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6166.910564] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.029447] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.054553] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.330506] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.558508] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4694]
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.590443] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1162..]
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.606538] usb 1-5: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.757695] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.757756] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.757815] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.759158] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.759856] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760146] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760147] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760148] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760149] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760149] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760151] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.760449] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-18-16-1.sfi
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.786257] OOM killer enabled.
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6167.786258] Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6168.003473] PM: suspend exit
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6168.103040] Generic PHY r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
Aug 25 12:48:25 otter kernel: [ 6168.228535] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Aug 25 12:48:26 otter kernel: [ 6169.356229] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Aug 25 12:48:26 otter kernel: [ 6169.357186] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1561623 usecs
Aug 25 12:48:26 otter kernel: [ 6169.357269] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Aug 25 12:48:26 otter kernel: [ 6169.370191] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12651 usecs
Aug 25 12:48:26 otter kernel: [ 6169.370280] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-18-16-1.ddc
Aug 25 12:48:26 otter kernel: [ 6169.373254] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.907697] wlp5s0: authenticate with d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.916293] wlp5s0: send auth to d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 (try 1/3)
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.968334] wlp5s0: authenticated
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.969066] wlp5s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.970317] wlp5s0: associate with d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 (try 1/3)
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.991940] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=3)
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6171.997470] wlp5s0: associated
Aug 25 12:48:29 otter kernel: [ 6172.105817] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
Aug 25 12:48:53 otter kernel: [ 6196.425145] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.425150] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.445224] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.449685] OOM killer disabled.
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.449686] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.451667] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.593960] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.924174] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.967248] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.976518] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.976518] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.976519] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.976525] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.977856] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.978918] irq_migrate_all_off_this_cpu: 5 callbacks suppressed
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.978919] IRQ 147: no longer affine to CPU2
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.979926] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.980969] IRQ 143: no longer affine to CPU3
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.982162] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.983222] IRQ 141: no longer affine to CPU4
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.983229] IRQ 149: no longer affine to CPU4
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.984425] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.985375] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.985378] IRQ 126: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.985381] IRQ 142: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.985385] IRQ 146: no longer affine to CPU5
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.986400] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.987382] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU6
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.987390] IRQ 144: no longer affine to CPU6
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.988404] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.990228] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.994368] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.994482] ACPI: EC: EC started
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6196.994483] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.000933] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.001056] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.001058] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.004723]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.006935] CPU1 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.006966] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.009127]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.009289] CPU2 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.009326] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.009800]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.009970] CPU3 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.009992] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.010460]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.010817] CPU4 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.010838] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.011367]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.011557] CPU5 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.011584] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.012053]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.012253] CPU6 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.012276] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.012744]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.012954] CPU7 is up
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.020145] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.058310] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning ON
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.059277] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.111962] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.218943] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.337171] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.362990] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.638947] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.866991] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4694]
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.899755] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1162..]
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6197.914974] usb 1-5: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.065877] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.065938] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.065997] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.066872] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.067991] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.067993] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.067994] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.067995] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.067996] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.067998] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.068003] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-18-16-1.sfi
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.068279] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.094706] OOM killer enabled.
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.094707] Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.282526] PM: suspend exit
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.370781] Generic PHY r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
Aug 25 12:48:57 otter kernel: [ 6198.496997] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Aug 25 12:48:58 otter kernel: [ 6199.559666] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Aug 25 12:48:58 otter kernel: [ 6199.559835] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1458570 usecs
Aug 25 12:48:58 otter kernel: [ 6199.559929] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Aug 25 12:48:58 otter kernel: [ 6199.572963] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12817 usecs
Aug 25 12:48:58 otter kernel: [ 6199.572965] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-18-16-1.ddc
Aug 25 12:48:58 otter kernel: [ 6199.575993] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.250831] wlp5s0: authenticate with d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.259197] wlp5s0: send auth to d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 (try 1/3)
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.312569] wlp5s0: authenticated
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.312833] wlp5s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.314799] wlp5s0: associate with d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 (try 1/3)
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.334347] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from d8:0d:17:bd:2a:42 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=3)
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.340497] wlp5s0: associated
Aug 25 12:49:01 otter kernel: [ 6202.450492] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
Aug 25 12:49:25 otter kernel: [ 6226.564293] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 25 13:39:50 otter kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xb8, date = 2019-03-30
Aug 25 13:39:50 otter kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.0.0-25-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-008) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)) #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 12:04:58 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 5.0.0-25.26-generic 5.0.18)
```

A few more results from later research, ideas by @nuts:

- `rmmod btusb` causes everything to function normally, suspend and wakeup works correctly (at least for a few seconds, I didn't check power drain).
- `modprobe btusb` back has new behavior: Now instead of stalling on suspend, the system will wakeup spontaneously immediately after suspend.

Any ideas on how to research this further?

Comment: hey @lutzky, sadly I don't have a solution yet but at least on my machines the Magic SysRQ keys still work. So instead of holding the power-button for 5 seconds you can probably do Alt-Print-S, Alt-Print-U, Alt-Print-B 
(sync harddrives, unmount harddrives, reboot machine) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: I did install and try kernels all the way down to 4.18.0-25 (5.0.0-16, 5.0.0-19, 5.0.0-20, 5.0.0-25) and with none of them the suspend worked. interestingly with older kernels suspending seemed to at least happen (led started blinking "suspended"ly, but waking up didnt work - system froze after hitting the power-button) instead of freezing before suspend (thinkpad led blinks forever in the "going to suspend now" state)
so probably it isnt the kernels fault 

Comment: An ubuntu 18.04(.3) live "CD" (pendrive) will suspend without problems. I tried it multiple in a row too.

Comment: can you try to a) `echo "disabled" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10/power/wakeup` and/or b) `sudo rmmod btusb`? reasoning: maybe the bluetooth driver is causing these problems. this way you disable it's power saving capabilities and/or remove the module

Comment: @nuts is definitely onto something. I haven't checked this since posting (I simply turned the system completely off all the time), but:

  * `rmmod btusb` causes suspend and wakeup to behave as expected (at least for a few seconds; didn't check battery drain and such)
  * `modprobe btusb` back again is now exhibiting different behavior - now suspend just fails immediately - brings the system out of suspend about 1sec after entering it, and system seems functioning normally.
  * I don't have `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10`, and no devices seem to have `power/wakeup`, so I couldn't test that.

Comment: I can also confirm that power drain is OK when suspended - roughly 1% per hour, which is about 0.5 watts.